# Error with index of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Why it doesn't work? 
P.S. I am beginner in Java.

```
int userInfo[];
userInfo = new int[2];
userInfo[0] = 11;
userInfo[1] = 20;
userInfo["result"] = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];

System.out.println(userInfo["result"]);
```

Comment: Because `userInfo["result"]` is not legal Java.

Comment: Why doesn't what work?  You define an array of `ints` then try to put a `string` in it...  Not to mention, you are trying to do a math operation on two indices as well.

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't include the error message.

Answer (score 9):

Only an `int` can be an index into an array.  A `String` won't work.  If you need 3 slots, declare your array to be length 3 and then you can use `userInfo[2]`.

The [JLS, Section 10.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) makes it pretty clear:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values.

Answer (score 4):

```
int userInfo[];
userInfo = new int[2];
userInfo[0] = 11;
userInfo[1] = 20;
int result = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];

System.out.println(result);
```

The string can not be the index in array.

Answer (score 2):

Your array has 2 slots, and you used them to store the numbers. To get the sum, do this:

```
int sum = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];
```

Also, even if your array had a third slot, you can only access individual elements by their numerical index (0, 1, or 2 in this case). Not by a `String` like result.

Answer (score 2):

In java, arrays only have zero and positive integer indexes. This means that an array can only be accessed with 0 to size of the array minus 1.

If you want to do something like:

```
userInfo["result"] = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];
```

You can try the following:

```
int result = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];
System.out.println(result);
```

or:

```
Map<String,Intgeer> example = new HashMap<String,Intgeer>();
example.put("result", new Integer(userInfo[0] + userInfo[1]));
System.out.println(example.get("result"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here as I mentioned in comments.  You declare an array of `int` here:

```
int userInfo[];
```

Then try to pass a `string` into it here (that won't work):

```
userInfo["result"];  // This is bad news
```

Your cleaned-up code should look like this:

```
int userInfo[];
userInfo = new int[2];
userInfo[0] = 11;
userInfo[1] = 20;
int sumArrayValues = userInfo[0] + userInfo[1];

System.out.println(sumArrayValues);
```

Happy coding!